# Ошибка: use of undeclared identifier 'qSort' в QT 6. Как побороть?

Tags: c++, qt, qsort, qt6

QT 6 не видит qSort, подскажите причину, в какой библиотеке находится, что подгрузить или альтернативный метод сортировки qVector.

`qSort(groups_fr.begin(), groups_fr.end());`

Я инженер, программирую в рамках своей деятельности, не во всем разбираюсь (

Comment: qSort устрел в qt5 и вроде как совсем убран в qt6, используйте рекомендуемую замену

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtalgorithms-obsolete.html#qSort

Comment: Просто замените на `std::sort`

Comment: std:: не помогает, это я уже проверял)

Comment: std::sort работает. Если у вас не работает, то покажите, как вы его используете, и что представляет из себя `groups_fr`.

Comment: Извиняюсь, действительно работает) Не понял почему раньше не работал.